# Какой смысл объявлять глобальную переменную не в начале?

Tags: c++, память, объявление

Наткнулся в книге Шилдта на такой пример :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

　extern int first, last; // Использование глобальных переменных.

　cout << first << " " << last << "\n";

　return 0;

}

// Глобальное определение переменных first и last.

int first = 10, last = 20;
```

То есть мы сначала объявляем переменную с помощью спецификатора памяти extern и только после ее определяем. Что в таких случаях мы выигрываем по сравнению с тем, если бы эти же переменные мы объявили в самом начале программы?

Comment: Такое вариант позволяет определить эти переменные в другой единице трансляции. Однако все это ни к чему, глобальные переменные, тем более из других единиц трансляции,  в С++ использовать не следует.

Comment: @VTT Я даже больше скажу - их нигде использовать не следует